# Markov processes and $C_0$-semigroups

Tags: markov-process, semigroup-of-operators

A Markov process $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ in continuous time on $\mathbb{R}^d$ can be described by a semigroup of [Markov kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_kernel)  $(p_t(x,A))_{t \geq 0}$ with $p_0(x,A) = 1_{A}(x)$ and which fulfill the [Chapman-Kolmogorov equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chapman%E2%80%93Kolmogorov_equation).

One can define the operator $$P_t f (x) := \mathbb{E}^x[f(X_t)] = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(y) \, p_t(x,dy)$$ 
on $L^\infty$ (set of all bounded, measurable functions)
and it then follows that $P_0 = Id$ and $P_t P_s = P_{t+s}$ hold.

My question is if $(P_t)$ is a [$C_0$-semigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0-semigroup). In other words, does $$|| P_t f - f || \to 0 $$
for any $f\in L^\infty$ when $t \to 0^+$ holds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general: no, $|| P_t f- f|| \to 0$ does not hold for all $f \in L^\infty$ and a general semigroup $(P_t)_{t\geq 0}$ on the Banach space $L^\infty$.

If e.g.  $P_t f(x) = f(x+ct)$ for some $c \neq 0$, then if $\hat{x}$ is a discontinuity point of $f$ problems appear: $P_t f(\hat{x}) - f(\hat{x}) = f(\hat{x}+ct) - f(\hat{x})$. This will not converge to $0$ as $t\to 0$. So norm convergence will even be more difficult.

It is often preferred to use other Banach spaces than $L^\infty$. Examples are $C_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$, $C_b(\mathbb{R}^d)$ or also $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$. I provide the link to the first two of these examples: https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/07/14/feller-processes/ and Section 6 in http://www.math.ist.utl.pt/~czaja/ISEM/internetseminar200607.pdf

Comment: Does $|| P_t f - f|| \to 0$ hold if you use $C_0(\mathbb{R}^d)$ or $C_b(\mathbb{R}^d)$ ?

Comment: For many prominent cases convergence holds, see the provided references. I think, though, that in general it does not hold. A try on a counterexample is the following: if your state space is $E=\{0,1\}$ instead of $E=\mathbb{R}^d$, then the semigroup generated by the transition densities $p_t(1,1)=1, p_t(1,0)=0$ and $p_t(0,0)=0$ and $p_t(0,1)=1$ for $t>0$ does not satisfy the required continuity (even pointwise). I cannot figure out right now how to transfer the example to $\mathbb{R}^d$...

Comment: If $(X_t)_{t\geq 0}$ is right-continuous and $P_t C_0 \subset C_0$, then $(1)$ always holds by dominated convergence.